# python - unescape in django template

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates, escaping

a = 'abc'

Html special characters in the show when the article.

```
> {{ a | escape }}

&#39;abc&#39;
```

When I show that I want to unescape.

```
> {{ a | escape | safe }}

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'safe'
```

An error occurs.

```
> from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

> a = mark_safe(a)
```

This error also occurs.

Django does not make the current is not applied to the safe?

Do you have any ideas on how to unescape?

(I is being developed in google-appengine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you are asking, but you can disable Django's automatic escaping with the [`autoescape` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape). For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> c = Context(dict(a = '<a href="#fragment">Link</a>'))
>>> Template("{{ a }}").render(c)
u'&lt;a href=&quot;#fragment&quot;&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;'
>>> Template("{% autoescape off %}{{ a }}{% endautoescape %}").render(c)
u'<a href="#fragment">Link</a>'
```

[`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) also works:

```
>>> from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
>>> Template("{{ a }}").render(Context(dict(a = mark_safe(a))))
u'<a href="#fragment">Link</a>'
```

Comment: Thank you.
Maybe I'm on an Django 0.96 version, use seems to be no.

Comment: If you're going to use `mark_safe` on App Engine, make sure you import `google.appengine._internal.django.utils.safestring`, otherwise it won't work.